# Object Oriented Model

Tags: java, object, oop, uml, class-diagram

I have a question and answer related to the Object oriented concept and I need help to understand the answer.
Below is an example where I have 2 classes 'Student' and 'Course'. I dont need code just the concept of how object model works.

[image: classes relation diagram]

Question: How would I get all the titles of the courses a student is taking?

Answer: From Student, I would traverse the relationship to Course and when I get to the Course I return the title of the Courses.

What does it mean to traverse the relationship? Doesn it mean to create List of objects of Student class inside Course class?

Comment: The relationship between `Student` and `Course` has to be modelled somehow. One possibility is to give each `Student` a field `Collection<Course> courses` (and expose it through a getter). Traversing this relationship means to get this field, i.e. to call the getter.

Comment: "Traverse" can mean different things.  Creating a List inside each Student is one possibility.  You could also have a graph with all students, like a Map, and you look up students and courses there.  It's just what makes sense for your particular design.

Comment: @Turing85 would you add as answer ?

Comment: @Lunatic [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74499025/4216641).

Comment: According to Webster's _traverse_ means "travel across or through". So in IT context to look for something in a stucture of any kind (array or tree).

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between `Student` and `Course` has to be modeled somehow. One possibility is to give each `Student` a field `Collection<Course> courses` (and expose it through a getter). Traversing this relationship means to get this field, by e.g. calling the getter.

Answer (score 2):

The ***association*** between `Student` and `Course` means that for each *instance* (object) of `Student`  there may or not be one or more  ***links*** to instances of `Course`. Formally, a link is defined in UML to be a tuple that identifies the objects at each end.

"Traversing" the association means to find for a `Student` all the  `Course`  with which the student is linked. How it is done is not specified, but there are two popular ways to implement this:

- Each `Student` object keeps a collection of courses linked with them.  In this case, traversing the association would consist of iterating through the collection.
- An object or collection representing the association keeps track of the links that exist between some `Student` and some `Course`. Traversing the association would then consist of finding the subset of links with a given `Student` at one end,  and iterating through this subset to find the linked `Course`.

**Note**: traversing is related to the UML concept of ***navigability***.  A navigable association from `Student` to `Course`, means that it's easy to traverse the association in this direction. Navigability can be unidirectional (e.g. if there is no efficient way for a course to find the linked students).